# Как скопировать лист Excel из одного файла в другой?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

Доброго времени суток.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы из заранее заготовленных Excel файлов брать листы и вставлять их в существующий документ.

Я перерыл весь интернет и почти нашел решение: читайте [ответ Cindy Meister](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d0971ec0-7d22-4c38-b686-b32e6bd01d44/how-to-copy-spreadsheet-to-another-excel-file-in-openxml?forum=oxmlsdk) и на основе его решения я сделал своё, но оно не работает если в таблице есть строковые переменные. Думаю что это как-то связано с тем, что у двух разных книг происходит конфликт, когда из первой книги я вставляю SharedStringTable во вторую. И как эту проблему преодолеть я не понимаю....

Привожу здесь код моего полу рабочего решения:

```
        public void CopySheet(SpreadsheetDocument sourceSpreadsheet, SpreadsheetDocument destanationSpreadsheet, string clonedSheetName, string destanationSheetName)
    {

        WorkbookPart sourceWorkbookPart = sourceSpreadsheet.WorkbookPart;
        WorkbookPart destanationWorkbookPart = destanationSpreadsheet.WorkbookPart;

        //Get the source sheet to be copied
        WorksheetPart sourceSheetPart = GetWorkSheetPart(sourceWorkbookPart, clonedSheetName);
        SharedStringTablePart sharedStringTable = sourceWorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
        WorkbookStylesPart workbookStyles = sourceWorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart;
        ThemePart theme = sourceWorkbookPart.ThemePart;

        //Take advantage of AddPart for deep cloning
        SpreadsheetDocument tempSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(new MemoryStream(), sourceSpreadsheet.DocumentType);
        WorkbookPart tempWorkbookPart = tempSheet.AddWorkbookPart();
        WorksheetPart tempWorksheetPart = tempWorkbookPart.AddPart<WorksheetPart>(sourceSheetPart);

        SharedStringTablePart tempsharedStringTable = tempWorkbookPart.AddPart<SharedStringTablePart>(sharedStringTable);
        WorkbookStylesPart tempWorkbookStyles = tempWorkbookPart.AddPart<WorkbookStylesPart>(workbookStyles);
        ThemePart tempTheme = tempWorkbookPart.AddPart<ThemePart>(theme);

        //Add cloned sheet and all associated parts to workbook
        WorksheetPart clonedSheet = destanationWorkbookPart.AddPart<WorksheetPart>(sourceSheetPart); // <--

        //Table definition parts are somewhat special and need unique ids...so let's make an id based on count
        int numTableDefParts = sourceSheetPart.GetPartsCountOfType<TableDefinitionPart>();
        int tableId = numTableDefParts;
        //Clean up table definition parts (tables need unique ids)
        if (numTableDefParts != 0)
        {
            FixupTableParts(clonedSheet, tableId);
        }
        //There should only be one sheet that has focus
        CleanView(clonedSheet);

        //Add new sheet to main workbook part
        Sheets sheets = destanationWorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
        Sheet copiedSheet = new Sheet();
        copiedSheet.Name = destanationSheetName;
        copiedSheet.Id = destanationWorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(clonedSheet);
        copiedSheet.SheetId = (uint)sheets.ChildElements.Count + 1;
        sheets.Append(copiedSheet);
        //Save Changes
        destanationWorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();


        destanationSpreadsheet.Close();
        sourceSpreadsheet.Close();
    }

    WorksheetPart GetWorkSheetPart(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string sheetName)
    {
        //Get the relationship id of the sheetname
        string relId = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name.Value.Equals(sheetName)).First().Id;
        return (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relId);
    }

    void CleanView(WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
    {
        //There can only be one sheet that has focus
        SheetViews views = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetViews>();
        if (views != null)
        {
            views.Remove();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
        }

    }

    void FixupTableParts(WorksheetPart worksheetPart, int tableId)
    {
        //Every table needs a unique id and name
        foreach (TableDefinitionPart tableDefPart in worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts)
        {
            tableId++;
            tableDefPart.Table.Id = (uint)tableId;
            tableDefPart.Table.DisplayName = "CopiedTable" + tableId;
            tableDefPart.Table.Name = "CopiedTable" + tableId;
            tableDefPart.Table.Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Зачем задавать [один и тот же вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/740831/213987) дважды?

Comment: Ну там вроде как решение было но потом я понял что это не решение и решил создать отдельный топик с вопросом

Comment: Нашел [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723395/how-to-aggregate-two-worksheets-to-one-workbook-using-openxml) но в нем используется сторонняя библиотека [Epplus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/)